# Save R file to a csv file that is organized like an excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, csv, write.table

I have loaded in my dataset "my dataset", added some new variables, and now wish to save it in my working directory as a csv file.

if I use write.table(my.data, file="newdata.csv", na=""), I get a spreadsheet that is not is not separated properly. I would like my variables along the top, and my values separated by columns according to those variables.

I have had trouble interpreting the R helppage on write.table, and would like to know which arguments I should enter so that my data can be written appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

"I would like my variables along the top" --> try using `col.names=T` in `write.table`, which will put your headings row on the top.

"and my values separated by columns according to those variables" -- uhh, `write.table` always does this. Do you mean that you want (say) a comma separator or tab separator instead of the default space? Then use the `sep=','` argument (that would put separator as a comma).

If you don't want row numbers to show up, use `row.names=F`.

`?write.table` explains it all pretty clearly, though it's possible I'm misunderstanding your question.

You can even just use `write.csv`, which is just a wrapper around `write.table` with comma as the separator.